# Get list of installed apps using Client Object Model

Tags: web-services, client-object-model, sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-addin

I have been trying hard to find any example, resource which explains how to get a list of installed apps in SharePoint 2013 environment using Client Object Model. So far I have found nothing.

Could you please share some links if you happen to know any that explains:

1. How to get list of apps installed in a SharePoint 2013 web using SP2013 **Managed** Client Object Model.
2. How to get list of apps installed in a SharePoint 2013 web using either WCF or REST service. -- I would really like to know how to do this as I need to create a WebPart in SP 2010 that lists apps installed in our SP 2013 Office 365 env.

Answer (score 3):

Use [AppCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.appcatalog_members%28v=office.15%29.aspx) class for this. Proof of concept below:

```
class StackExchangeProof
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var login    = "admin@yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com";
        var password = "YourHardP@ssw0rd";
        var url      = "https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com";

        var creds  = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, ToSecureString(password));

        using (var context = new ClientContext(url))
        {
            context.Credentials = creds;

            var apps = AppCatalog.GetAppInstances(context, context.Web);
            context.Load(apps);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var app in apps)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("App Name: {0} - {1}", app.Title, app.Status);
            }
        }
    }

    public static SecureString ToSecureString(string source)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source))
            return null;

        var result = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in source)
            result.AppendChar(c);

        return result;
    }
}
```